# Is there a way to share/link to files on a hub site with an associated site, or vice versa?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, hub-site

My organization is reviewing a way to move forward with file storage and one of the scenarios we will face is content that currently exists on a classic Team site in SharePoint Online that we would like to somehow associate with a Microsoft Team, specifically with the SharePoint Online backend site for the team that gets automatically created.

I had thought a Hub site would be a way to do this; by setting the Microsoft Teams-created SP site as a Hub and then associating the classic Team site with it, I was hoping to be able to see the content linked or available between the two sites... because that seems to me to be the prime use in something like linking a site to a Hub (*otherwise why leave the classic 'site -> subsite' schema of yesteryear which worked fine?*)

However, I cannot seem to find a way to link content between the two sites, or make content from one site available in another. Is there some way to do this? I can't even search for content in one of the other sites as [this article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online/) suggests:

> ### Search within a Hub
>
> Once you create a Hub and connect other sites to it, you will notice that a Search Box on the Main Hub now searches across other sites within a Hub. This is amazing!
>
> [image: 'Search Across Sites' image]

(I can't even find that "Search Across Sites" box/option. I only see one Search field centered at the top of the viewport).

I guess I'm not really seeing any point/use in associating sites with a Hub site at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements will only work in a hub site. You can treat hub site as a information portal where you can access all the information from associated sites, however this is not vice versa. You will not be able to search information across sites in an associated site.  For more information about hub site, have a check on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-a-sharepoint-hub-site-fe26ae84-14b7-45b6-a6d1-948b3966427f).

For making content from one site available in another, have a try with [highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd).